# count number of logins by specific user django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is their any way of counting number of django logins?
The last_login field of the auth_user gets updated with each login.
Can we make use of that field to count number of logins by a specific user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in a sense.  You'll need either a field in you app's `UserProfile` model to hold number of logins or a separate model for storing full login history.  Then add signal handlers for last_login updates and record them in a model of your choice.  Here's my example:

```
from django.db import models, signals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserLogin(models.Model):
    """Represent users' logins, one per record"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(user) 
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

def user_presave(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.last_login:
        old = instance.__class__.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        if instance.last_login != old.last_login:
            instance.userlogin_set.create(timestamp=instance.last_login)

signals.pre_save.connect(user_presave, sender=User)
```

Comment: It's a matter of style, but where would you put this in django (what file?). Would you create a new app? Thanks.

Comment: `UserProfile` goes to `models.py`, signal handler goes to `listeners.py`, both in your main application.

Comment: This gave me problem when trying to create users (as user didn't exist yet. I switched to `post_save` which solved the problem

Comment: I don't understand "instance" in the user_presave method.  How does it get set?  It doesn't appear to be an argument when connect is called.  Only the sender argument is set.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

There's also a 'user_logged_in' signal that'll do the trick with out the need to check for last logins etc.

```
class UserLogin(models.Model):
    """Represent users' logins, one per record"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(user) 
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def update_user_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    user.userlogin_set.create(timestamp=timezone.now())
    user.save()

user_logged_in.connect(update_user_login)
```

Comment: I added this bit to my UserProfile model, but it doesn't appear to be firing off on user login (account_userlogin table is created). any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did (using django 1.7), similar to Guy Bowden answer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

class LoginUpdate(models.Model):
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    action_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

def update_user_login(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    LoginUpdate.objects.create(action_type="Login", action_user=user)

user_logged_in.connect(update_user_login, sender=User)
```

Later you can count number of logins, in your views.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented it but I'm stuck at how counting the number of logins, and display them in the admin. Should I work in admin.py, views.py, models.py ? (django beginnner here)

Comment: @juminet, the method i provided, ONLY saves 'date_updated', 'action_type' and 'action_user', in our database. then you can count 'action_type' for a specific user, using django queryset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#count) . So your queryset should look like this: LoginUpdate.objects.filter(action_type="Login", action_user=SPECIFIC_USER).count()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-timeStamps](https://github.com/zandegran/django-timeStamp) to store rcent login times. A simple light weight tool.