# Django - tracking authenticated users page vistis

Tags: django

I want to be able to track authenticated users page visits for my internal application, ive looked through https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/analytics/ but i cant see one that meets the requirements.

All i need to know is what my authenciated users are visiting and how many times.

for example, or somethign alike

```
User       | logins | total page visits | most visited url  | last visited url
John Smith | 100    | 2000              | sitedetails/1     | sitedetails/50
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526966/count-number-of-logins-by-specific-user-django  -> This will give you the number of logins, but for total page visits and other fields, you will have to create your models and write logic in views for the same as specified in marcusshep's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All i need to know is what my authenciated users are visiting and how many times.

First thing that comes to mind is creating a model with a foreign key to user and a charfield for the view that they requested.

```
class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    view = models.CharField(max_length=250) # this could also represent a URL
    visits = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

This will give you the ability to count the number of times a user has hit a page.

```
def some_view(req, *a, **kw):
    # try to find the current users request counter object
    request_counter = Request.objects.filter(
        user__username=req.user.username, 
        view="some_view"
    )
    if request_counter:
        # if it exists add to it
        request_counter[0].visits += 1
        request_counter.save()
    else:
        # otherwise create it and set its visits to one.
        Request.objects.create(
            user=req.user,
            visits=1,
            view="some_view"
        )
```

If you take the time you can isolate this logic into one well written function and call it at the beginning of each view.

```
def another_view(req, *a, **kw):
    count_request() # all logic implemented inside this func.
```

Alternatively with class based views.

```
class RequestCounterView(View):
    
    def dispatch(req, *a, **kw):
        # do request counting
        return super(RequestCounterView, self).dispatch(*a, **kw)


class ChildView(RequestCounterView):
    def get(req, *a, **kw):
        # continue with regular view
        # this and all other views that inherit 
        # from RequestCounterView will inherently 
        # count their requests based on user.
```