# Count and store Number of logins in Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django framework. I am trying to record number of logins by a particular user(s) and display it in my Django panel. I went through the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526966/count-number-of-logins-by-specific-user-django)

But could not understand which code is to put in which file i mean what to put in models.py and signals.py or otherwise.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

create signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Profile

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged(sender,request,user,**kwargs):
    user.profile.log_count+=1
    user.profile.save()
```

create `Profile` model, if exists add `log_count` field.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    log_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: I implemented the above code in the signals.py and 2nd one in models.py

it gives me 502 Bad Gateway on the browser. any comments.

Comment: did you migrate after you add log_count  field?

Comment: I restarted the service using supervisorctl restart <servicename>

Comment: can you share the error page if it is on debug?